# Elixir: how to use flush() function in script?

Tags: elixir

Documentation gives example of usage in `iex` - and it works there:
http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#send-and-receive

Though it doesn't work inside of script:

```
$ elixir e.exs
** (CompileError) e.exs:6: undefined function flush/0
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

I found that this function is part of some `IEx.Helpers`
https://hexdocs.pm/iex/master/IEx.Helpers.html

But prepending `use IEx.Helpers` or `use IEx` at the beginning of script doesn't give effect.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, uou could also simply run `$ iex e.exs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not want to use the `use` keyword. You are going to either want `alias` or `import`.

They are all related, but slightly different.

- `import Foo.Bar` - will import all of the functions defined in the `Foo.Bar` module allowing you to call `function()`
- `alias Foo.Bar` - will also import all of the functions defined in the module `Foo.Bar`. The difference is that now you need to use `Bar.function()` instead of just `function()`.
- `use Foo.Bar` - will call a macro inside of the `Foo.Bar` module called `__using__/1`.

You can read more about the difference of these words and more [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html).